# React Native Reanimated animatable properties list

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated

Animated api as documented [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#caveats) can only animate natively non-layout properties.

Reanimated on the other hand does not document this kind of info (at least I could not find it). I can see from a github [issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/376) that there is a [config file](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/blob/82f6608799a2ea1667bb8c801e3bf9cf6ee1a144/src/ConfigHelper.js) that has  `UI_THREAD_PROPS_WHITELIST`   and `NATIVE_THREAD_PROPS_WHITELIST`.  Does anyone know why are they separate and potential performance implications?